# Installing libwebsocket.so shared library

Tags: ubuntu, libwebsockets, .so

I am having problems getting the libwebsockets.so shared library on a 32 bit system.I installed it from the git source on a 64-bit ubuntu without any problem.

I tried to do the same on a 32-bit ubuntu 14.04 VM and 32 bit ubuntu lucid chroot. It failed to generate "**.so**" file in both the cases.

I even tried installing it via the package  "libwebsockets-dev" . The package just installed the header files but ".so" file was still missing.

How can the "**libwebsocket.so**" be generated through installation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to install the websockets library on different 32 bit machines with different processor architectures, I thought of installing the libwebsockets-dev from the debian source.

dpkg -i <--the libwebsocket package-->

showed that there was a missing dependency libwebsockets3. This was not shown when compiled from the git source.

Then I installed the missing dependency libwebsockets3 and then installed the libwebsockets-dev package.Now the "libwebsockets.so" shared library is generated.